# Sending and Receiving a xml object (unmarshall)

Tags: rest, jaxb, resteasy

I am trying to receive this object in my web service from a html page. In the browser opened by eclipse works fine but when i try the same thing in firefox i get the fallowing problem:

Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", local:"userclient"). Expected elements are <{}userclient>

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Userclient {

    @XmlElement
    private String first_name;

    @XmlElement
    private String last_name;

    @XmlElement
    private String email;

    public Userclient() {
    }
//....
}

//Reciving

    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public Response addUser(Userclient user,
            @CookieParam("sessionId") String sessionCookie) {
}


//Sending
<script>

RestServlet.addUser({
$entity : userclient
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please show the XML you are sending to your web service? Do you use a namespace for `userclient` root element?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options for solving your problem based on what your XML looks like:

### Option #1 - elementFormDefault="unqualified"

**Input XML**

If in your XML only the global (top level) elements are namespace qualified:

```xml
<ns:userclient xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <first_name>Jane</first_name>
<ns:userclient>
```

**Userclient.java**

Then you could just specify the `namespace` parameter on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

```java
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
public class Userclient {
```

### Option #2 - elementFormDefault="qualified"

**Input XML**

If all the elements are namespace qualified like:

```xml
<userclient xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <first_name>Jane</first_name>
<userclient>
```

**package-info.java**

You can use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to apply namespace qualification to your model.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

Below is a link to an article on my blog that covers more about JAXB and namespace qualification:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

---

### Note

You are currently adding more annotations than are necessary.  JAXB is configuration by exception so you only need to add annotations where you want the XML representation to differ from the default.

**For More Information**

Below is a link to an article on my blog that covers more about JAXB's default XML representation:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Userclient {

    private String first_name;

    private String last_name;

    private String email;

    public Userclient() {
    }
//....
}
```